# What is the answer to the bonus question in test_changing_hashes of Ruby Koans?

Tags: ruby

In the [Ruby Koans](http://rubykoans.com), the section about_hashes.rb includes the following code and comment:

```
def test_changing_hashes
    hash = { :one => "uno", :two => "dos" }
    hash[:one] = "eins"

    expected = { :one => "eins", :two => "dos" }
    assert_equal true, expected == hash

    # Bonus Question: Why was "expected" broken out into a variable
    # rather than used as a literal?
end
```

I can't figure out the answer to the bonus question in the comment - I tried actually doing the substitution they suggest, and the result is the same. All I can figure out is that it is for readability, but I don't see general programming advice like that called out elsewhere in this tutorial.

(I know this sounds like something that would already be answered somewhere, but I can't dig up anything authoritative.)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

It's because you can't use something like this:

```
assert_equal { :one => "eins", :two => "dos" }, hash
```

Ruby thinks  that `{ ... }` is a block, so it should be "broken out into a variable", but you can always use `assert_equal({ :one => "eins", :two => "dos" }, hash)`

Comment: I totally like that answer, except that when I actually tried to substitute the hash as you suggest, it still worked fine and the assert passed. EDIT - no I didn't - I made the lesser change that left the assert comparing against 'true'. I'll try your suggestion and so I can watch it break. :) Thanks!

Comment: That did make it break, thanks again. I don't feel too bad about it, since the Koans haven't even introduced me to the concept of 'blocks' yet.

Comment: (ruby noob here) so as we have already made the change to use a variable, why don't we just use (assert_equal expected, hash) but rather use (assert_equal true, expected == hash)?

Comment: that answer is wrong. Koans and OP, would not write code as above.
If it was going to be literal, it would look as follows:

`assert_equal true, { :one => "eins", :two => "dos" } == hash`

Comment: The last assert doesn't work anymore (yeah it has been 10+years, ruby version 3.0.2p107); What works is: `assert_equal ({ :one => "eins", :two => "dos" }), hash`

Answer (score 2):

I thought it was more readable, but you can still do something like this:

```
assert_equal true, { :one => "eins", :two => "dos" } == hash
```

Comment: That has the disadvantage of not displaying the actual values and is more verbose than `assert hash == { :one => "eins", :two => "dos" }`. (I suspect but do not know that the order has to be reversed as I have done.)

Answer (score 0):

Another test you can use is the following:

```
assert_equal hash, {:one => "eins", :two => "dos"}
```

I’ve simply swapped the parameters to `assert_equal`.
In this case Ruby will not throw an exception.

But it still seems a bad solution to me. It’s much more readable using a separate variable and testing a boolean condition.

Comment: I'm assuming you actually meant `assert_equal hash, { :one => "eins", :two => "dos" }`

Comment: For some reason, the signature of the assertion functions is _"(expected, actual)"_. `hash` is _"actual"_, it should not be the first argument. It does not matter if the assertion succeeds but using the arguments in the wrong order produces confusing messages when the assertion fails.

Answer (score 0):

I compare the variable expected with the hash, not broke

```
expected = { :one => 'eins', :two => "dos" }

assert_equal expected, hash
```